# VB Script to C# - Extract .arch file

Tags: c#, exception, vbscript, extract, zip

I have to extract .arch type files. In an old VB script, it is done using wscript.shell commands.

```
Set shellobj = wscript.createobject ("wscript.shell")
cmdline = "wzunzip -d -n " & source & " " & destination & "\"
cmdexec = shellobj.run((cmdline), 1, true)
```

I am converting this to c# so I used the following code to extract files:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(source, destination);//Unzip file
```

But this line is throwing an exception for **.arch** type files.

> "An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file."

Is there a way I can extract .arch type files in C#. My file is of this specific type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the MS Docs?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_ExtractToDirectory_System_String_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_

Under IO Exception:

> The directory specified by destinationDirectoryName
>   already exists.
>
> -or-
>
> The name of an entry in the archive is Empty, contains only white
>   space, or contains at least one invalid character.
>
> -or-
>
> Extracting an archive entry would create a file that is outside the
>   directory specified by destinationDirectoryName. (For example, this
>   might happen if the entry name contains parent directory accessors.)
>
> -or-
>
> An archive entry to extract has the same name as an entry that has
>   already been extracted from the same archive.

So basically,

- Does your directory already exist? If so it shouldn't.
- Are any of the file name's empty? If so, they shouldn't be, they require names.
- Does the destination file path have any file path characters (for
  example, '..')? If so, they shouldn't.
- Do any of the files have the same name? If so they shouldn't.

It doesn't actually look like any of those issues weirdly, and it's rare Microsoft miss something. The only other thing I see in the docs is that there is an overload for an encoding type, but this is for the encoding of the zip file rather than the files inside it...

It looks like the file is corrupt. This question seems to highlight your issue:
https://superuser.com/questions/457271/identifiying-a-zip-file-that-is-not-really-a-zip-file

Maybe when the .ARCH files are compressed, the file signature is lost? Or the file is corrupted somehow?

Comment: Thanks for your answer I checked those. But now, It looks like "ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(source, destination);" is working for .zip files. But not for **.arch** type files. Is there any specific way to create .arch files. I am not sure if the one I created for testing purposes is corrupted or wrong.

Comment: How did you create the .arch file? Did you just grab any old file and change the file extention? 

I've not came across this file type and not really heard of it either, even google doesn't provide much, whoever you're developing this for, ask them for a test file to use rather than creating your own.